# Why is Pytorch giving me a datatype error: Float vs Double?

Tags: python, types, pytorch

I am working on migrating some working Pytorch code I found online (which is a 2D image classification example using the MNIST data; apologies that I lost track of the original source and am unable to find it) to what I need, which is converting a 1D collection of values into a numerical score.  I created my own Dataset class.  When I call model(), I get an error: `RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #2 'mat1' in call to _th_addmm`.  My first level of confusion is that I can't find any reference to Python even having a Double datatype.  And my second is why I get the error--when I put in debug code to show the datatype of mat1 and its elements, I am told that it is a Tensor which claims to be float64.  I also wonder why it is expecting a scalar for mat1, which the documentation describes as a matrix/tensor.

The full error dump is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mlalan.py", line 174, in <module>
    outputs = model(images)
  File "/usr/home/adf/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "mlalan.py", line 80, in forward
    x = activate(self.fc1(x))
  File "/usr/home/adf/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/home/adf/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 87, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/usr/home/adf/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1610, in linear
    ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #2 'mat1' in call to _th_addmm
```

Some of the key code from my Dataset class is

```
class RandomDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file, transform=None):
        self.data_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file, dtype=float)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        raw = self.data_frame.values[idx]
        sample = raw[0:6], raw[6:8]
        return sample
```

The full source code is at http://8wheels.org/mlalan.py.

Comment: Try turning it into a float, float(num)

Comment: BTW, float64 is Double; Float is float32. Pandas is probably loading the data with double-precision.

Comment: Your model requires a FloatTensor. Call (some_tensor).float() to whatever tensors are going in as inputs to your nn.Module instance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, in Python, float means float32.  However, in Pandas and Numpy, float means float64.  I was able to resolve the problem by adding a call to astype as below.  The "32" is required for it to work.

```
raw = self.data_frame.values[idx].astype(np.float32)
```

Thanks!

Now I can move on to the next crash :-)